# Incrementing id of apex:pageblock

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce, apex

I wanted to know if it was possible to set an ID that increments in the  section. I know that we can set an id, as it's a valid atribute; however, I would like to know how i can set an id that increments (or references a variable that increments).

Can I define a variable (apex:variable) or something else in the vf page that can then be incrememnted via a loop (apex:repeat)?

eg: `<apex:variable var="i" value="{!0}"/>`

Then in my code I would have: `<apex:pageBlock id="'RandomText-'+{!i}">`

and in the apex:repeat would have: `<apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>` which would increment the variable.

Would this work?

Example of code:

```
//DEFINE VARIABLE:
<apex:variable var="i" value="{!0}"/>

<apex:pageBlock>
<apex:pageMessages />

<table id="contacts">
    <thead>
      //Create table headers
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <apex:repeat value="{!selected}" var="c">

        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit" id="'Randomtext-'+{!i}" mode="edit">
          //Iterate through the selected records

          <apex:variable var="i" value="{!i+1}"/>
        </apex:pageBlock>
      </apex:repeat>
    </tbody>
</table>

</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above code should work. I am also doing the same thing increasing the variable value by +1 in page block table. Please see the below code for your reference.

```
<apex:variable var="schIndex" value="{!0}" />
    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!schedules}" var="sch" title="Existing Schedules">
        <apex:column>
            <apex:commandLink value="Edit" action="{!editSchedule}" rerender="scheduleSection">
               <apex:param name="selectedScheduleId" value="{!schIndex}" />
            </apex:commandLink>
            <apex:variable var="schIndex" value="{!(schIndex+1)}" />
         </apex:column>

        <apex:column value="{!name}"/>                      
   </apex:pageBlockTable>
```